# Sonata Admin Action Button to Pre Filtered List

Tags: symfony, button, action, addition, sonata-admin

I am rather new to Symfony (2 weeks) so forgive my ignorance.

I am trying to add a custom action button that will link to a pre filtered  list of a RELATED entity.  I have done a lot of research but can't quite seem to find what I need.

Currently I have two entities Books and Authors with a manyToOne relation ship.
I have these set up in Sonata Admin in the usual way and all works well. I even have an author filter on the book list page which I am hoping can be leveraged to accomplish my goal.

In the Author list view, I would like to add an action button on each row next to View and Edit, called "View Books By Author".  I can get the button but fail to correctly build the URL.

I have 3 issues with the routing:

1) I am trying to use admin.generateObjectUrl() or similar in my button template to cleanly build an admin URL but can't get a path to an alternate entity. In my case, since I am currently viewing authors, the links always point to the author entity not books as I would like.

2) I am uncertain how to get the id of the current author in order to pass it to the filters

3) I am uncertain how to cleanly build the filter query string parameters.  I could do it by hand if necessary: bookEntityListPath + "?filter[author][value][]=" + $authorID
But obviously this is not that clean and I would prefer a better method if possible.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue and started trying out some code when I could not find an answer. Using the path() twig method (route to path conversion) it is quite easy to create a link like that.

See this documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#generating-urls-from-a-template

Your link would look something like this:

```
<a href="{{ path('admin_application_book_list', {
  'filter[author][value]': object.id  
}) }}" class="btn btn-small">
```

With 'admin_application_book_list' being the path to the list of books (bookEntityListPath?) and object.id being the id of your author (would have the name object in a detail or edit template of that entity)