# Custom Action leading to filtered list with multiple parameters?

Tags: symfony, twig, sonata-admin, sonata

I need that my custom action button leads to a filtered Sonata List (Curriculum), but I need to use two parameters (Company and External).

Previously, I have been using this approach: [Sonata Admin Action Button to Pre Filtered List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897847/sonata-admin-action-button-to-pre-filtered-list), but I couldn't manage to use two parameters at the same time.

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-default" href="{{ path('admin_myvendor_mybundle_curriculum_list',{'filter[companies][value]' : object.id }) }}"><i class="fa fa-university"></i> Curriculums </a>
```

Any idea how to solve this? I thought about creating a controller and using a custom QueryBuilder but I still want to use Sonata list (and without overwriting my default ListMapper in Admin)

Answer (score 0):

What you will need to do to achieve this is override the `createQuery()` method in your admin.

the tricky part is that the original query for the list uses `SELECT DISTINCT` so for each order by that you will add to the query you will need to add the same field to the select statement.

https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/1548

In one of my bundles i used a workaround to automatically add fields in order by clauses to the select part of the query by extending the ProxyQuery class.

if you want to have a look: https://github.com/blast-project/DoctrinePgsqlBundle/blob/master/Datagrid/ProxyQuery.php the magic happens between line 98 and line 112

Comment: The problem is that I'm already overriding the createQuery() method for my 'default' listing...I need two listings, a default list view (in which I'm already using createQuery()), and another with filtered results (but keeping using the sonata list without requiring to override templates and all that)

Comment: I'm sorry i must have misunderstood your question.You want to have a link to a list and another link to another list or one list filtered by two values ?

Comment: Default list (already using createQuery) and another list with filtered values